# Spinnaker with Redhat, Amazon AMI or CentOS?

Tags: spinnaker

Was wondering if anyone has installed spinnaker on a machine that isn't running Ubuntu or Mac. According to the [spinnaker github](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker) they only have instructions for those two but seems possible for others. Assume I can not use either of those. Can it work on RHEL, amazon, etc? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Diana Tkachenko from Stitch Fix recently gave a talk on the steps she had to take for Amazon Linux. You might find it useful - https://youtu.be/ywzPblFpIE0 . ( starts around 30 minutes in )

Comment: Did she document, anywhere, any of the steps she took.  The presentation is great but does she have a github or anything?

Comment: I found her slides but building RPMs for some of the components are failing for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can work on RPM based distro's with a bit of extra work (I know of folks running on Amazon Linux) - the project is only publishing deb files currently, so you have to build from source to get RPM packages for each of the components.

for each of the service git repos executing `./gradlew buildRpm` will produce an installable RPM.

Comment: Will there be a build script added for amazon/rhel in the future? I am having trouble getting gradle to build everything. Edited the build.gradle packages but can only get RPM's to be created for some of the components. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can  Install spinnaker on Redhat by using Docker , Install docker on Redhat , then install Spinnaker on the docker , as docker can be installed anywhere and anything can be installed on docker files ..